# How can I use an IC family or adapter to switch automatically from solar cell to batteries & reverse?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX975U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can I use an IC family or adapter to switch automatically from solar cell to batteries & reverse ?

if no load => solar cells charges the batteries

```
if there is a load 
     then 
        if p2 > p1 then trigger makes comparator connects load power from CELL
        else (p1 > p2) then trigger makes comparator connects load power from  batteries
     else 
        CELLS charges the batteries
     fi
fi
```

Is there some specialized IC to manage something like this as "comparator" 
is this a bad approach of the need? (and then if you have ideas please provides them).

This is not really similar to : [this question](https://despora.de/uploads/images/scaled_full_b4625726a4bad081f974.jpg) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a battery charger/manager IC.

They come in all sorts of flavors, so you'll need to look for one that meets your needs.  They can be simple "smart" switches, or more complex, incorporating DC-DC converters and possibly even peak power tracking on the solar cell.

I would start with a Digi-key search for "battery charger" (https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-battery-chargers/781), and I would also browse the power management ICs from Analog Devices (https://www.analog.com/en/products/power-management/battery-management.html).  I'm sure countless other IC manufacturers have good selections as well, but it will take some browsing to find the right part for your situation.

Here's an example of a part that might work for you:

[image]

Comment: thanks, It's maybe the solution, I'm going to look at that & learn about them and if possible choose the right one,  that feed my needs.